# Keep subset of records separately for query performance mysql

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I have a large table containing over 10 million records and It will keep growing. I am performing an aggregation query (count of particular value) on records of last 24 hours. The time taken by this query will keep increasing with number of records in the table.

I can limit the time taken by keeping these 24 hours records in separate table and perform aggregation on that table. Does mysql provide any functionality to handle this kind of scenario?

Table schema and query for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE purchases (
    Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ProductId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    CustomerId int(11) NOT NULL, 
    PurchaseDateTime datetime(3) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Id), 
    KEY ix_purchases_PurchaseDateTime (PurchaseDateTime) USING BTREE, 
    KEY ix_purchases_ProductId (ProductId) USING BTREE, 
    KEY ix_purchases_CustomerId (CustomerId) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

select COALESCE(sum(ProductId = v_ProductId), 0),
       COALESCE(sum(CustomerId = v_CustomerId), 0)
    into v_ProductCount, v_CustomerCount
    from purchases
    where PurchaseDateTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      and (   ProductId = v_ProductId
           or CustomerId = v_CustomerId );
```

Comment: Answered but after having re-read your question, maybe some form of partition would provide a strictly table based solution. This would need benchmarking against any alternatives as I'm not sure about performance implications off the top of my head. See this answer for further guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200359/how-to-partition-mysql-table-by-day

Answer (score 1):

Build and maintain a separate [*Summary table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

With partitioning, you might get a small improvement, or you might get no improvement.  With a summary table, you might get a factor of 10 improvement.

The summary table could have a 1-day resolution, or you might need 1-hour.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for what you currently have, so we can discuss more specifics.

(There is no built-in mechanism for what you want.)

Comment: It's also VERY dependant on the INDEXing that is in place. A proper index will speed things a LOT

Comment: Following is the table schema: 
`CREATE TABLE purchases (
   Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ProductId int(11) NOT NULL,
   CustomerId int(11) NOT NULL,
   PurchaseDateTime datetime(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
   KEY ix_purchases_PurchaseDateTime (PurchaseDateTime) USING BTREE,
   KEY ix_purchases_ProductId (ProductId) USING BTREE,
   KEY ix_purchases_CustomerId (CustomerId) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` How can I create a summary table for last 24 hours?

Comment: Please show us the `SELECT` you are currently using for aggregation.

Comment: That table looks a lot like a many:many mapping table, but with a poor choice of indexes.  See [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: @RickJames added select query for reference.

Comment: This many:many mapping table can have duplicate mappings (in case some customer buys same product multiple times) so need to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY_KEY`.

Comment: @ctor - OK, you will need some changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

I would leave off

```
      and (   ProductId = v_ProductId
           or CustomerId = v_CustomerId )
```

since the rest of the query will simply deal with it anyway.

Then I would add

```
INDEX(PurchaseDateTime, ProductId, CustomerId)
```

which would be "covering" -- that is, the entire `SELECT` can be performed in the INDEX's BTree.  It would also be 'clustered' in the sense that *all* the data needed would be consecutively stored in the index.  Yes, the datetime is deliberately first.  (`OR` is a nuisance to optimize.  I don't trust the Optimizer to do "index merge union".)

**Plan B**

If you expect to touch very few rows (because of `v_ProductId` and `v_CustomerId`), then the following may be faster, in spite of being more complex:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(ProductId = v_ProductId), 0)
    INTO v_ProductCount
    FROM purchases
    WHERE PurchaseDateTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND ProductId = v_ProductId;
SELECT COALESCE(sum(CustomerId = v_CustomerId), 0)
    INTO v_CustomerCount
    FROM purchases
    WHERE PurchaseDateTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND CustomerId = v_CustomerId;
```

together with both:

```
INDEX(ProductId, PurchaseDateTime),
INDEX(CustomerId, PurchaseDateTime)
```

Yes, the order of the columns is deliberately different.

**Original Question**

Both of these approaches are better than your original suggestion of a separate table.  These isolate the data in one part of an index (or two indexes), thereby having the effect of "separate".  And these do the task with less effort on your part.

Comment: But the execution time of these queries will keep increasing as the table grows because index lookup time will be increasing. So Isn't it better to keep the last 24 hours (or 2 days) records separate so that index lookup time of this table remain constant while the original table grows.

Comment: A point-query in a million row table takes X milliseconds; in a trillion-row table, it takes only 2X milliseconds.  That is, the slowdown is very minor.  Have you tried the indexes and reforumlations I suggested?  Are those the only `SELECTs` you are concerned about?