# Storing temporary daily data in spring boot REST application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a Restful API that gathers some data everyday in specific time range and interval, e.g. from 9:00 to 12:00 AM every 5 minutes. Data are saved in a MySQL database. My API itself serves data to front-end. 
My problem is that I have a huge amount of data in my DB, millions of records to say, and I need some in-day calculations (which are not dependent to data of the days before). So I decided to store the data for each day in a temporary place to gain fast queries and calculations.

I have considered some choices:

1. Using in-memory databases such as H2. I've noticed that this kind of database is not suitable for use in production level. And I don't know if it is possible to use H2 and MySQL concurrently.
2. Using a temporary MySQL table and flush it every morning.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What about a simple in memory cache, e.g. with a `Map`?

Comment: You should read the the manual about Partitioning https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data?

Comment: And this can help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200359/how-to-partition-mysql-table-by-day

Comment: And another question. Do you have performance problems now when querying the database? And do you have indeces for your queries?

Comment: Can you also give us examples of the kind of calculations you are doing?

Comment: If what you want to do is clear your DB on a daily basis (or perform specific operations on it) you should look at CRON jobs. Explained here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: @Lino That is another choice but I think using traditional SQL based queries are more straight-forward.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli At this point each simple select query takes about 12 seconds. That is a little slow. 
I am using this table for about 6 months. Can I re-partition it or I must create a new schema and dump old data?

Comment: @Reg Each record has about 20 numeric and string fields. Calculation are like average and min or max.

Comment: @Terry I am using cron right now! Thanks.

Comment: @ImanH does it answer your issue then?

Comment: @Terry No I have some issues with performance not scheduling.

Comment: @ImanH okay. Maybe you could share some SQL code with us, especially the simple query that takes about 12 seconds to compute? Thanks.

Comment: Min / Max and averages can be calculated on the fly? No need for database queries? Is that an option?

Comment: @Reg these are calculated after query